# Won't emission line spectrum also be observed in absorption spectrum?

Tags: atomic-physics

In absorption spectrum, we pass white light through the sample of gas or liquid which is to be examined. The electrons in those atoms will will absorb particular wavelengths from the white light and will get excited to a higher energy level. The wavelength which are absorbed by the electrons won't appear in the screen and hence dark lines should be observed in a coloured background if the light is further passed through a prism or a diffraction grating. In this way and absorption spectrum is obtained in which dark lines appear in a coloured background. But we know that electrons don't like to stay in higher energy level. They typically stay there for a time that is of the order of $10^{-8} s$. So they will jump back to the ground level either by one transition or by multiple transitions and thus they will the emit the energy in the form of photons. If they come back to the ground level in one transition they will emit photon which has the exact wavelength of a photon that they absorbed. Thus we won't say see dark lines in a coloured background as the electron emitted the photon of the exact same wavelength with it absorb which we see as dark lines in a coloured background, right?

Comment: The incoming light should be directed, so that the white light passes through the gas and onto a screen. You are correct that new photons will be emitted in deexcitation, but these photons will be emitted in totally random directions, not all directed at the screen. Hence, while there is still a change that some of these reemitted photons will reach the screen, we can expect the luminosity of those to be far lowert than the non-absorbed light.

Comment: have a look to see that your model is not correct, as absorption and emission spectra are measured https://www.nagwa.com/en/worksheets/658148208480/

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the answer by @DakkVader, the reemitted photons will be radiated in all possible directions, i.e., the fraction of these photons hitting the detector is very small.

Another reason that is important in practice is that the relaxation to the ground state lay happen via non-radiative mechanisms.

Finally, it is necessarily to point out that what we discuss here is the *absorption spectroscopy*, which is complimentary to the emission spectroscopy, in which the atoms are excited, and then their emission spectrum is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Re-emitted photons may travel in any direction, with only a fraction of these hitting the detector. Thus there will still be less light at the detector at these frequencies.

There is an emission mechanism called *stimulated emission*, which is when an incoming photon stimulates an excited atom into releasing a photon identical to the one stimulating the process. This is for example how lasers (light amplification by *stimulated emission* of radiation). If the re-emission you speak of only consisted of stimulated photons, there would be less of a dip. But since you'd have a finite measurement time in the instrument, and a finite time which it takes to stimulate photons, you'd have a small dip anyway.

Comment: this is an interesting way to do reflected spectroscopy